# Simple registration form will not inset into db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple registration form (which does not need to be too secure, as its just to see who is participating.) However, whatever I try to do, I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from, email, phone, accommodation, nights, room, talk, comments,
>   pass) VALUES ' at line 1

Code:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO participants (name, from, email, phone, accommodation, nights, room, talk, comments, pass) VALUES 
                ('$name', '$from', '$email', '$phone', '$accommodation', '$nights', '$room', '$talk', '$comments', '$pass')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use the `mysqli_*` functions as `mysql_`are deprecated

Comment: Use prepared statements..Try PDO

Comment: I think you must check that you're sending `strings` to table fields type `varchar` or `char` and `integers` to integers fields, And so. When you '$variable' you are sending strings! :)

Answer (score 2):

`FROM` is a [reserved word in SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to put it in quotes.

```
(`name`, `from`, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO participants (name, from, email, phone, accommodation, nights, room, talk, comments, pass) VALUES 
           ($name, $from, $email, $phone, $accommodation, $nights, $room, $talk, $comments, $pass)") or die(mysql_error());
```

but..

`FROM` it is reserve word..

Reserved Words

[MySql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)